# PHP calculator width html form

Tags: php, html, forms, isset

can't figure out why my form will not work.

it has to calculate area of a rectangle.
Form has to disappear after submit and show answer in a sentence.

php code has to check if form is filled and submitted, then hide it and echo the answer,
I'm just learning, so sorry if it seems too easy of an issue.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

if(!isset($_POST['length'], $_POST['width']))

{
  function area($a, $b) {
    $sum = $a * $b;
    echo "rectangle, with  $a cm in length and $b cm in width, area is $sum square cm.";}
    area($_POST['length'], $_POST['width']);  
} }

else { ?>
<form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF; ?>" method="POST">
        Length: <input type="text" name="length" />
        Width: <input type="text" name="width" />
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: There are several erros in your  code. Wondering what error messages you get.

Comment: Why don't you use javascript instead of php? It is too simple to use php and send data to server.

Comment: You never called the function area().. It doesn't work if you only write the code to make a function, u need to call it too... And By the way why are u using function since u r only using it once.

Comment: @GerarddeVisser it's working great, sorry for long respond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` instead of `$_PHP_SELF` to post to the current url. Or just leave it empty.

Also the `isset` check is incorrect.

With below code, it should work:

```php
<?php
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    if (isset($_POST['length'], $_POST['width'])) {
        function area($a, $b)
        {
            $sum = $a * $b;
            echo "rectangle, with  $a cm in length and $b cm in width, area is $sum square cm.";
        }

        area($_POST['length'], $_POST['width']);
    }
} else { ?>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
        Length: <input type="text" name="length"/>
        Width: <input type="text" name="width"/>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
<?php } ?>
```